# Cant call flickr api with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, flickr

Im running this code in my website to get the photos on a set, but I always end up getting error. The console log show "parsererror". What am I doing wrong?

middle.php

```
<?php die(file_get_contents($_REQUEST['url'])); ?>
```

script.js

```
//Flickr
var url = encodeURIComponent('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=1408bff5f72a4b84b924d13e8562b6a2&photoset_id=77649470@N03&photoset_id=72157629903184261&format=json');
$.ajax({
    url: "middle.php?url="+url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(){
        console.log("yes");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textstatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("nooo");
        console.log( textstatus );
    }
});
```

Comment: This code looks kosher. Perhaps there is an error elsewhere in your code?

Comment: [Same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're having a problem because of cross-domain security issues, you'll want to create a 'middle man' page. I will use PHP for my example. I will create a `middle.php` that accept a different-domain url, fetches the text/code, and returns it. My JS will see this as a same-site request, and all will be dandy.

**middle.php**

```
<?php die(file_get_contents($_REQUEST['url'])); ?>
```

If PHP isn't what you use, you can apply the same strategy in your own environment.

Then your ajax call will look like this..

```
var url = encodeURIComponent('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=1408bff5f72a4b84b924d13e8562b6a2&photoset_id=77649470@N03&photoset_id=72157629903184261&format=json');

$.ajax({
    url: "middle.php?url="+url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(){
        console.log("yes");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textstatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("nooo");
        console.log( textstatus );
    }
});
```

However, I like to use `getJSON()` for fetching JSON data, more so than `ajax()`

```
$.getJSON("middle.php?url="+url, function(obj){
    if (obj.photoset){
        console.log("Success");
    } else {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont get it... why my index.php cant get it, but middle.php can?

Comment: Because index.php is using JAVASCRIPT to fetch it, while middle.php is not. Same-Domain security (for the sake of this discussion) only applies to JS and is regulated by your browser.

Comment: man, that last comment was awesome. I didnt know it. But im still getting a pasererror :S

Comment: What I needed is: header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: Ahh, I forgot about the headers :)